# Arreglar o cambiar el método push.apply

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando la manera de arreglar un error que tengo con el método de push.apply. Me dí cuenta de que si le pasó 5 caracteres, éste se sobrecarga y no termina. Tira el error " too many arguments provided for a function call"

Lo que quiero es que el código me diga todas las combinaciones posibles dependiendo del valor de length.

Por ejemplo, si length es 1. Solo muestra: a b c e... hasta llegar a z
Si length es 2. Solo muestra: aa ab ac ad... hasta llegar a zz

Todo ésto lo hace bien, el problema ocurre si le pongo la length en 5 o más cuando lo llamó así:

```
combinaciones_letras(letterDB, 5, '')
```

Este es el código:

```
var letterDB = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "ñ", "o", "p", "q", 
"r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
"K", "L", "M", "N", "Ñ", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

function combinaciones_letras(letterDB, length, curstr) {
    if(curstr.length == length) return [ curstr ];
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < letterDB.length; i++) {
        ret.push.apply(ret, combinaciones_letras(letterDB, length, curstr + letterDB[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Que extraño, yo si puedo observar todos las combinaciones posibles... cual sería el problema en sí?

Comment: Lo pongo en JsFiddle y tira el mismo error "too many arguments provided for a function call"

Comment: Que es `letterDB`? que letras le estás pasando para que te muestre ese mensaje?

Comment: vos sabes a mi me funciona con 1 2 o 3, si pongo 5 me tira callstacksize exceeded

Comment: esto se da por la recursividad exesiva. deberias remplantear tu codigo

Comment: se, intenta alguna forma mas eficiente de hacer tu algorirmo

Comment: Veo que tu objetivo es en `ret` ir acumulando todas las posibles combinaciones... porque no cambias ese push.apply por `ret = [...ret, ...combinaciones_letras(letterDB, length, curstr + letterDB[i])];`. Porque el problema es que hay un numero máximo de parametros que se le pueden pasar a una funcion (y que depende del navegador que uses) y al usar push.apply estas pasando cada valor como un parametro distinto, y de ahí viene el error. o quizas tambien cambiarlo por un `ret = ret.concat(combinaciones_letras(letterDB, length, curstr + letterDB[i]));`